# Android Studio Emulator: WHPX: failed to enable partition

Tags: android, emulation, hyper-v, amd-processor, whpx

I am trying to get the Android Emulator to work with my Ryzen 2700X CPU but I always get the following error:

```
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to enable partition extended X64MsrExit and X64CpuidExit hr=80070057
Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64.exe: failed to initialize WHPX: Invalid argument.
```

I made sure the latest Emulator version is installed and Windows Hypervisor, Hyper-V and virtualization in BIOS are all enabled.
I searched for answers for a while but could not find any solution to this problem.

EDIT: 
After deleting the Nexus5X device and re-creating it with Pie x86 it worked fine. Make sure to check the following:

- activate Visualization in your BIOS (SVM Mode)
- Android Studio and Emulator are up-to-date
- Windows Hypervisor and Hyper-V-Hypervisor in Windows Features are activated (uncheck Hyper-V-Services)
- run Android Studio as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

I think you've done all the setups well.

but
Do you use Windows 1903 version?
That version has an issue for Ryzen CPU Virtualization.

as a solution

You can update the Windows version

Or Revert to the previous version.

Or you can update it to a preview version.

Comment: I have this very same issue on AMD Ryzen. I'm running Windows 11.

Comment: @JohanPaul The problem is probably similar to the one above (Error in Windows). You can probably get this information from the Microsoft Windows 11 community.